# Does Rouche's Theorem apply INSIDE and ON the contour?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

If the criteria is satisfied for Rouche's theorem to be applied to two complex functions i.e. it is such that $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the contour and both functions are analytic on the contour. Does this mean that $|g(z)|$ and $|f(z) + g(z)|$ have the same number of zeros **inside** and **on** the contour?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because if $|f| < |g|$ then neither $g$ nor $f+g$ is zero.